# Ignore files on monorepo

Tags: neovim, telescope.nvim

I'm working on a monorepo, which means I have to constantly switch between folders (say `web` and `server`). I noticed that when I open a file from project "A" the ignored file patterns works as expected, but when I switch to project "B" the ignored patterns don't work.

```
.
├── server <-- 1. I open a file here and node_modules is ignored
└── web <-- 2. I open a file here and node_modules is not ignored
```

Here's my telescope setup.

```lua
require('telescope').setup{
    file_ignore_patterns = {"dist", "node_modules", ".git"},
    shorten_path = true,
    color_devicons = true
}
```

I already tried using wildcards on the file patterns like `**/node_modules`, but I'm not sure which pattern might work.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a bug, maybe just a config error.

Comment: Issue trackers are not only for  bugs.